# How to import data from TXT or XML file into Powershell textbox or listbox

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm looking for a way to import a TXT or XML (preferred) file into powershell and then show the information in a large textbox or listbox (I've been trying both). The reason I'd prefer XML is that there are 3 sections and I don't want 3 different files. This is for a GUI script that has a "help" button which pops up a smaller GUI window. The help window has 3 buttons, How To Use, Error Msgs, and Update Notes. I'd like the XML file to look like this...

```
<Help>
<HowTo>
    Text line 1
    Text line 2
    Text line 3
</HowTo>
<Errors>
    More text
</Errors>
<Updates>
    More text
</Updates>
</Help>
```

Each button would show the appropriate XML text in a large textbox. I can get it to show the text from the XML just fine, however I can't figure out how to have it display correctly on new lines like I have it typed in the XML file itself. In the example above I'd click the "How To Use" button and it'd show the 3 lines like it does above. If it tried that now it would show like...

```
Text line1Text line 2Text line 3
```

I'm currently trying to make it work with a textbox that has multiline enabled so it does wrap around when it gets too long, but there are no proper line breaks. I've tried formatting the XML lines to force a line break, but it didn't work.

```
Text line 1 `r`n
Text line 2 `r`n
etc.
```

I'm currently using Get-Content to save the TXT or XML file into a variable. If there's another way to allow it to keep it's formatting that would be helpful. I haven't been able to find anything.

---

UPDATE: Trying labels

Using labels keeps the correct formatting, and it re-sizes the window correctly, however when the window re-sizes the buttons stay where they're at. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Is there a way for the buttons to follow the box when it's resized, and is there any vertical scroll option? Each button will have a good amount of text so it'll  probably need to scroll.

Comment: can you use a Label instead of a TextBox or ListBox? i think labels can make use of carriage returns/line feeds

Comment: That looks promising, I'll try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

example using Label

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 

$display = [xml]@'
<Help>
<HowTo>
    Text line 1
    Text line 2
    Text line 3
</HowTo>
<Errors>
    these are the errors
</Errors>
<Updates>
    update notes here
</Updates>
</Help>
'@

# Build Form
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form.Text = 'INFO'
        $Form.Width = 330
        $Form.Height = 243
        $Form.AutoSizeMode = 'GrowAndShrink'
        $Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
# Build Label
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $Label.Text = ''
        $Label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Consolas', 9)
        $Label.AutoSize = $true
        $label.Left = 10
        $label.Top = 0
# Build OK Button
    $howtobutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $howtobutton.Left = 10
        $howtobutton.Top = 170
        $howtobutton.width = 100
        $howtobutton.Text = 'How To'
        $howtobutton.Add_Click({$Label.Text = $display.Help.HowTo})
# Build OK Button
    $errorsbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $errorsbutton.Left = 110
        $errorsbutton.Top = 170
        $errorsbutton.width = 100
        $errorsbutton.Text = 'Errors'
        $errorsbutton.Add_Click({$Label.Text = $display.Help.Errors})
# Build OK Button
    $updatebutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $updatebutton.Left = 210
        $updatebutton.Top = 170
        $updatebutton.width = 100
        $updatebutton.Text = 'Update Notes'
        $updatebutton.Add_Click({$Label.Text = $display.Help.Updates})
# Use Enter/Esc key
    $Form.KeyPreview = $True
    $Form.Add_KeyDown({
        if ($_.KeyCode -eq 'Escape') {
            $Form.Close()
        }
    })
# Add Controls to Form
    $Form.Controls.Add($howtobutton)
    $Form.Controls.Add($errorsbutton)
    $Form.Controls.Add($updatebutton)
    $form.controls.Add($label)
    [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```